# IntelliJ : debugging new HashSet() step by step : field gets initialized without seeing it

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, hashset

I don't know if the issue is caused by my version of the JDK, my version of IntelliJ or to by lack of Java complete understanding.
I was checking `HashSet` implementation, and I wanted to know when the field `keySet` is initialized. I saw the method

```
public Set<K> keySet() {
    Set<K> ks = keySet;
    if (ks == null) {
        ks = new KeySet();
        keySet = ks;
    }
    return ks;
}
```

which seems to be the place where the field is set the first time, but when I put my breakpoint on the condition, `ks` is never null!
So I decided to check at what moment it is initialized but I don't seem to find it.
I simply ran the following instruction (1) step by step by using IntelliJ's *Force Step Into* button :

```
HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>();
```

I get to the instruction (2) :

```
map = new HashMap<>();
```

And to the instruction (3)

```
 this.loadFactor = DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR;
```

After the instruction (3), just before leaving the constructor `public HashMap()`, if I evaluate the field `keySet`, it is still null.
But right after that, exactly after instruction (2), before leaving the constructor `public HashSet()`, if I evaluate `map.keySet` it is not null anymore!

What kind of sorcery is this? Am I missing something here or is it an issue with my debugger?
I am using jdk-9.0.1 and IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you debug, the debugger will try to show you the content of the `HashSet`, so it calls the sets `toString()` method, which indirectly calls the `keySet()` method of the backing `HashMap` object, thereby initializing the `keySet` field.

The debugger ignores breakpoints while it's making a call to `toString()`, so you don't see the call.

Comment: You're right, I didn't think of checking the implementation of the `toString()` method. I updated IntelliJ to 2018.3.2 because I thought that it was a bug and with the new version it tells me explicitly : *Skipped breakpoint at ... because it happened inside debugger evaluation*. It all makes sense now because can only call `toString()` once the object has been fully created, so at the end of the constructor. However I have two more questions :

Comment: Why does it call `toString()` although it never use the result? In the debugger, instead of showing the result of `toString()`, it only shows *size = 0* instead of *{}*. I don't find the place where it uses it.

Comment: Right after the instruction (3), so when the `HashMap` has been created, if I evaluate `this.toString()`, it should create the field `keySet` (since it also call `keySet()` )but if I evaluate the field right after that, it is still `null`. So why does it work with the `HashSet`but not with the `HashMap`?

Comment: I think I have the answer for the first question : It seems that *view as Collection* call `toString()`. To prevent the `toString()` evaluation of the `Set`, I had to disable **both** *Enable toString()* and *Enable alternative view for Collection classes* in the [Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189708/is-it-possible-to-tell-intellij-idea-to-automatically-invoke-tostring-on-the-o)

Comment: Map's `toString()` doesn't call `keySet()`. Set's `toString()` calls `iterator()`, which delegates to its maps `keySet().iterator()`.

Comment: You're right, sorry I mixed up `keySet ` and `entrySet`.