# Mockito unfinished stubbing exception detected ONLY in Intellij Debugger

Tags: spring-boot, debugging, intellij-idea, mockito, stub

The problem only occurs when I am trying to debug a test via the IntelliJ debugger. It does not happen when I just simply run the test.

CustomerChoiceRepository is a normal Spring Boot JPA repository which here is being mocked with `@Mock`.

[image]

When this line executes in the debugger I get the following error in the watch section of the variables:

[image]

The entire error message is:

```
Method threw 'org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException' exception. Cannot evaluate com.item.repository.jpa.CustomerChoiceRepository$MockitoMock$1318657964.toString()
```

Again this is only is detected in the IntelliJ debugger, as a result the test fails *only* when I am debugging it.

So my question is: what is happening here?

Is this a bug ? Is this something that I fail to understand because I do not know the internals of Mockito particularly well ?

Comment: Could you prepare and provide a minimal reproducible project sample? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your IntelliJ is calling toString on the mock during stubbing, which causes the exception.

**Check your debugger settings**

By default, IntelliJ calls `toString` on objects in debugger window, but only on objects that override that method. This behaviour is customizable, currently in `Preferences -> Build Tools -> Debugger -> Data Views -> Java -> Enable 'toString' object view`, but the settings mey differ between IDE versions.

See:

- [Is it possible to tell IntelliJ IDEA to automatically invoke toString() on the objects inspected in watches, variables, tool tip windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189708/is-it-possible-to-tell-intellij-idea-to-automatically-invoke-tostring-on-the-o)

**Don't call methods on mocked object during stubbing**

See:

- [How do Mockito matchers work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822512/how-do-mockito-matchers-work)
- [How does mockito when() invocation work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440270/how-does-mockito-when-invocation-work)

Comment: Sir thank you so much. You have saved me a ton of headache.