# Mocking of KubernetesClient throws InvalidUseOfMatchersException: Could not evaluate toString()

Tags: java, mockito, fabric8

for my test I need to mock a `io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClient`.
This is what my test looks like:

```java
    @Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
    KubernetesClient kubernetesClient;

    ...

    @Test
    void dummyTest() {
        when(kubernetesClient.resources(any()).inNamespace(eq("integration")).withName(eq("bar")).get()).thenReturn(createMockSubscriptionResource());
        ...
    }
```

I would expect that this line would create a deep-stub for this method-chain.
However, when I execute the test I get the following exception:

```
Method threw 'org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException' exception. Cannot evaluate io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClient$MockitoMock$1322763925.toString()
```

This results in a null-pointer-exception. I am wondering why Mockito is trying to call `.toString()` and why I am getting this error at all. Can anyone give me a hint here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this happen in your IDE? In a debug run?

Comment: Yes, this happens during a debug-run of the test.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.1 (Ultimate Edition) - Build #IU-213.6461.79, built on December 28, 2021

Comment: Then it must be a variant of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69628236/1570854

Comment: Thanks a lot! The solution from this thread solved this issue. However, I still get a null-pointer-exception in the line. But that seems to be another error.