# Mocking ApacheHttp classes results in null

Tags: java, mockito

I am using `mockito core4.4.0` and `JUnit5` and have test:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@MockitoSettings(strictness = Strictness.LENIENT)
class ElasticSearchLoggerTest {

    private CloseableHttpClient client;
    private CloseableHttpResponse response;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        response = Mockito.mock(CloseableHttpResponse.class);
        client = Mockito.mock(CloseableHttpClient.class);
    }
   ....
}
```

However, this mocking results in NPE, i tried to use `@Mock` annotation instead of Mocking with `Mockito.mock()` but the result is the same.

Why is this null?

Comment: Are response or client really `null` or is NPE thrown during usage?

Comment: @ChristophDahlen i checked , right after mocking in debugger it says `Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient$MockitoMock$268347003.toString()`

Comment: @ChristophDahlen however when i run the tests using maven it behaves correctly for some reason

Comment: Please post entire stack trace. Note that debugging mockito code has some tricky parts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69626405/mockito-unfinished-stubbing-exception-detected-only-in-intellij-debugger/69628236

Comment: thats it, only NPE