# org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: ArrayList cannot be returned by toString() in Junit5 test

Tags: mockito, junit5

I want to mock the following code:

```
  @Mock
  private AvailableService availableService;

........

public List<String> getAccountIds(Qualifier qualifier, String method, AccountType type,
      Long id) {
    List<String> accountIds = .......
    return accountIds;
  }

.........


public AvailableMethod getByAccountId(String accountId) {
    return .....;
  }

.........

    given(availableService.getAccountIds(any(), any(String.class),
            any(AccountGroupType.class), any(Long.class))).willReturn(Arrays.asList("1998"));
        given(availableService.getByAccountId(anyString()))
            .willReturn(getStatus(AccountStatus.ENABLED));
```

But I get the following issue:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
ArrayList cannot be returned by toString()
toString() should return String
***
If you're unsure why you're getting above error read on.
Due to the nature of the syntax above problem might occur because:
1. This exception *might* occur in wrongly written multi-threaded tests.
   Please refer to Mockito FAQ on limitations of concurrency testing.
2. A spy is stubbed using when(spy.foo()).then() syntax. It is safer to stub spies - 
   - with doReturn|Throw() family of methods. More in javadocs for Mockito.spy() method.
```

How you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: You must show the method signatures `getAccountIds` and `getAccountId`, otherwise it is impossible to help. I assume `availableService` is a mock (`Mockito.mock` or `@Mock`)? If it is a spy, the second bullet point of the error message applies

Comment: Done. Post is updated.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue locally (Mockito 4.5.1, JDK 17) and defining the remaining interfaces that are missing from your question. Note that your method expects an `AccountType`, but your stub uses a matcher for `AccountGroupType`, so the test shouldn't compile in the first place. You are not re-assigning field `availableService` with a different value somewhere in your test class, per chance?

Comment: Yes, it should be `AccountGroupType` into above example. Copy/paste mistake

Comment: You didn't answer my last sentence. Could you please show the full test (annotations, class definition, fields with initializers, setup method, test method) and include stubs for all required classes/interfaces (with only the necessary (public) methods; if overloaded methods with identical names exist, please include both)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mockito unfinished stubbing exception detected ONLY in Intellij Debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69626405/mockito-unfinished-stubbing-exception-detected-only-in-intellij-debugger)

Comment: Another helpful post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822512/how-do-mockito-matchers-work