# Mockito thows InvalidUseOfMatchersException only during debugging

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I stub it to this in my unit test code:

Here is my unit test class:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class SQSS3EventHandlerTest2 {

    @MockBean
    private MediaProcessingService mediaProcessingService;


    @InjectMocks
    @Autowired
    private SQSS3EventHandler handler;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
    }

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() {
    }

    @Test
    void apply() throws IOException, InterruptedException, MetadataExtractionFailureException {
        S3ObjectMetadata s3ObjectMetadata = new S3ObjectMetadata();
        s3ObjectMetadata.setContentType("audio/wav");
        s3ObjectMetadata.setContentLength(9L);
        Map<String, String> bucketDtlMap = Map.of("bucket", "unit-test-bucket", "key", "2023/123456/15.wav");

        MultimediaFileResponse mediaProcessResp = new MultimediaFileResponse();
        S3ObjectTags s3ObjectTags = new S3ObjectTags();
        s3ObjectTags.setBitDepth("16");
        s3ObjectTags.setFormat("Wav");
        s3ObjectTags.setSamplingFrequency("44100");
        s3ObjectTags.setTotalDuration("9");
        s3ObjectTags.setCodec("pcm_s16le");
        mediaProcessResp.setS3ObjectTags(s3ObjectTags);

        when(mediaProcessingService.insertMultimediaMetadata(anyMap())).thenReturn(mediaProcessResp);

        boolean res = handler.updateArtefactAndTags(s3ObjectMetadata, bucketDtlMap, ArtefactInput.classType.SOUND.name());
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

Here is my service class:

@Service

```
public class MediaProcessingServiceImpl implements MediaProcessingService {


    public MultimediaFileResponse insertMultimediaMetadata(Map<String, String> bucketDtlMap)
                throws MetadataExtractionFailureException {
            MultimediaFileResponse multimediaFileResponse = null;
          // code logic and http call to other servicer. it is removed

            return multimediaFileResponse;
        }

}
```

it gives error. What is wrong with this mock?

```
Method threw 'org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException' exception. Cannot evaluate org.service.mediaprocessing.MediaProcessingService$MockitoMock$7570iSIH.toString()
```

Comment: can you add the whole stacktrace ?

Comment: What exactly are you testing? Why do you use SpringBootTest annotation for Integration tests with MockitoExtension for unit tests? Why are you trying to mock behavior for the method you are testing?

Comment: When does this error happen? Always or only when run in the debugger? On top of that +1 for @Feelfree's comment.

Comment: Feel free I am just doing a unit test, not an integration test. Mokito is new to me.  Btw, when I rerun without the debugger, it goes fine. Exception only happens during debugging time. When I commented SpringBootTest, The test didn't instantiate @Autowired. I guess I must need  SpringBootTest to have the bean instantiated.

Comment: Why do you mock behavior for method from service class. What is the SQSS3EventHandler class, how is he related to insertMultimediaMetadata()? Can you share related code?
You don't have any Asserts or verify.

Comment: SQSS3EventHandler is AWS lambda handler class.  SQSS3EventHandler class uses the service mediaProcessingService to process multimedia files such as audio video images etc. The question is how come it works when I run? But exception from Mokito when debugging?

Comment: You must not mix `@SpringBootTest` and `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` (and you must not annotate a single field with `@Autowired` and `@InjectMocks`). Something is fishy. Did you already try the `doReturn` form of Mockito?

Comment: The implementation of `MediaProcessingServiceImpl` is irrevaent, because you are not using it. You are creating a mock bean for `MediaProcessingService`, so the real code of the implementation does not matter. What is the code of `updateArtefactAndTags`? (that's the important bit). But first you need to fix your annotations

Comment: what kind of annotation fix is required here? Also the question it works fine when run. But throw exception when debugging. Wh?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mockito unfinished stubbing exception detected ONLY in Intellij Debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69626405/mockito-unfinished-stubbing-exception-detected-only-in-intellij-debugger)

Comment: Thx. I think that is the issue with the debugger